# Roughness reflectance relationship

Tags: optics, photons, reflection

i am confused about a result in paper related to reflectivity from etched hole in silicon. The reflectance oscillation varies with surface roughness but i am not getting similar oscillation while simulating in fdtd lumerical. the model paper is based on fresnel equation.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.